# Cannot #include <dirent.h> in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When I include `dirent.h` (`#include <dirent.h>`) in Visual Studio 2005, I get the error:

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'dirent.h': No such file or directory

I am new to C++; can anyone please provide me with the solution for this error?

Comment: I answered this in another question from the same user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228405/list-the-files-in-particular-folder-in-c-closed. This question should be closed.

Comment: Manuel: that doesn't seem like the same question, and is closed anyway.

Comment: I don't see that your answer did directly address this.

Comment: @Neil - I said that he had to be on Unix to use dirent.h. Doesn't that address this?

Comment: @Manuel It might address it, but it is wrong. I use dirent.h on Windows, but then I am using MinGW.

Comment: @Neil - yes and you can use windows.h on Linux with wine. Anyway, even if my answer in the other thread wasn't 100% accurate, the right thing to do would have been to discuss it in the comments to *that* thread, not starting a new one.

Comment: @Manuel, I see that you did provide that information in the other question. Unfortunately, people searching for the information as to why dirent.h can't be found on their Windows box will take one look at that question and not read any further. Far better to answer it here where the question will match the answer.

Comment: @Manuel MinGW doesn't require an emulator - it produces native Windows executables . And I never read "that thread" beyond posting my comment on it.

Comment: @paxdiablo - OK, apparently I have a different view than everyone else. Let's forget it, and apologies if I've been too picky.

Answer (score 3):

The file dirent.h is not a C++ Standard header file. As you are on Windows, you probably want to use the [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28VS.85%29.aspx) and related functions, declared in windows.h

Comment: He said in another thread that he wanted to keep multiplatform.

Comment: @Manuel In general, it's a good idea to address the question posed in a particular thread.

Answer (score 2):

The error message says it all. The file does not exist or it is not in the correct directory. Check out this [website](http://www.softagalleria.net/dirent.php). It includes a free implementation of `dirent.h`.

Comment: So, how about closing this question?

Comment: Questions don't get close unless they're not real questions for some reason.  They should get an accepted answer though, @SHIVA.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the directory where the file is located to the "additional include folders" in the Visual Studio project properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try including just `dir.h` and if that doesn't work try `io.h`

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

bool canDelete(int timeCreate);

int main() {
    struct _finddata_t data;
    int handle;
    handle = _findfirst("test.txt", &data);

    if(handle == -1) {
        exit(1);
    }

    if(canDelete(data.time_create)) {
        cout << "Deleting file ...\n\n";
    } else {
        cout << "File ok.\n\n";
    }
}
/**
* @param: the time in seconds that the file was created.
* @return: true if the file was created more than 7 days, 
* false otherwise.
**/
bool canDelete(int time_create) {
    time_t seconds = time(NULL);
    int days = 7;
    int max_time = 60 * 60 * 24 * days;
    int time_passed = seconds - time_create;
    if(time_passed > max_time) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```